# Summarizing Fields based on content in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, qgis-custom-function

already read many answers for similar questions, but i didnt find a solution for my problem. Dont know how to start.

Problem: shp with about 50 fields. Each field contain NULL, 1 or 2. Now i need two new fields. One containing the number of fields with "1", the other with "2".

I am using QGis 2.16.2 and 2.14; OS Win10

I'm trying [@Joseph's solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211788/115), add the hint [@kyle reed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211831/83121) and make some modifications to start as an expression:

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def R1func(feature, parent):
    lists = []
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        f = feat.fields()
        num = f.count()
        for i in range(num):
             if feat[i] == 2:
                 lists.append(i)

    return len(set(lists))
```

and also try a short version

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def R2func(feature, parent):
    lists = [] 
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    for feat in layer.getFeatures(): 
        lists.append(feat.fields())

    return lists.count(2)
```

Version 1 returns for every row `60` (for number 1) or `37` (for number 2)
Version 2 returns `0`

Maybe i make a mistake.

Comment: QGIS version? OS?
Personally I would do this in Excel, export to CSV, import in QGIS and then join.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a bit of python, you could obtain the number of fields which contains a specific value. Use the following in the **Python Console** and change the value:

```
lists = []
layer = iface.activeLayer()  
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    f = feat.fields()
    num = f.count()
    for i in range(num):
        # Look for fields with a value of 1
        if feat[i] == 1:
            lists.append(i)

print len(set(lists))
```

Then use the printed value as the expression when adding a new field. Repeat for your second value.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to count the values in each row, you could use the following in the **Function Editor** of the Field Calculator:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import qgis

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def counting(value1, feature, parent):
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    return feature.attributes().count(value1)
```

Then type as the *expression*:

```
counting(1)
```

This will count all values which equal `1` for each row in each field.

---

*Note that if you use it twice, it will also count the values in the **new field** that was created previosuly, in which case you would have to subtract all values greater than zero by one.*

Comment: ok, get the error "name 'iface' is not defined"

Comment: not completly understand your code. isnt it twice the same? Doesnt the function count already return the number in an array?

    lists = []
    layer = iface.activeLayer()  
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        lists.append(feat.fields())
   
    print lists.count(1)

Comment: i'd put the code into the question

Comment: @S.Wiwa - Does each field only contain one value? E.g. All rows in "Field_X" only has a value of `1`. Or do fields contain more than one value? The code I posted only assumes that each field contains one constant value.

Comment: No, its different. Every row has a different combination, e.g. row 1 and 3 in "Field_X" contain `1`, row 2 `NULL`, row 4 and 5 `2`. --> i need an array for every row, and get the number of `1`or `2`in the array with `len`or `count`, right?

Comment: @S.Wiwa - Thanks for clarifying, I've edited my post =)

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfect. Only manually filter for the second number the results of the first number, so i could -1

Comment: @S.Wiwa - Most welcome, glad it worked =)

Answer (score -2):

You could try:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()?
```

I do not know why you still need to use it in the latest QGIS.

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thx.
Next problem arise,i modified the question